# Compiz Memory leak

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, memory, memory-leak

After sluggish performance and freezing for two weeks I finally managed to nail down the culprit to Compiz, I found out it's vital to Unity and is basically an OpenGL wrapper for Ubuntu and Xorg.

How do I fix this? There's plenty of bug reports, but none of them give an indication on how to do a 'quick fix' before they fix the memory issue.

I also get 'System Error' messages during startup and the details show that Xorg is crashing.

Should I do a clean install?

Comment: Often, there is no "quick fix". Your best bet is to make these bugs as affecting you(requires a Launchpad account, then the link above the bug details) so their heat increases, possibly inducing higher priority or a developer to work on the issue.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS You've basically answered the question. I recommending posting that as an answer.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, especially in your case, there is no "quick fix". Your best bet is to make these bugs as affecting you(requires a Launchpad account, then the link above the bug details) so their heat increases, possibly inducing higher priority or a developer to work on the issue. If you post links to these bugs here, then other users will be able to do the same.